# How to recurse without changing variables

Tags: python, recursion

Hello so I was wondering if there is a way to recurse through a function without changing the value of variables.

Here is my code:

```
def helper_list_range(self, low, high, rangelist):
    if self is EmptyValue:
        return rangelist

    else:
        if self.left is not None and self.right is not None:
            if self.root <= high and self.root >= low:
                rangelist.append(self.root)

            self.left.helper_list_range(rangelist) 
            self.right.helper_list_range(rangelist) 

            return rangelist


def list_range(self, low, high):

    rangelist = []
    self.helper_list_range(low, high, rangelist)
    return rangelist
```

As you can see that I am using a helper function so that I append to the **rangelist** without changing its value when the function does a recursion.

I was wondering is there a way I can do this without using a helper function. Using a helper function just seems a bit obscure.

Comment: The helper function doesn't have anything to do with "appending to rangelist without changing its value". The helper function is the thing that does all the work, using the empty list passed in from the main function.

Comment: Yes I created the empty list in the main function, but if I were to create it in the helper function. The list would become empty again.. once the function recursed. So I was wondering, if we can have the list in the same function as where the recursion is taking place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you look for default arguments:

```
def list_range(self, low, high, rangelist = None):

    if rangelist is None:
        rangelist = []
    # here goes the code of helper_list_range
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I wouldn't use self as a parameter. It's better to pass in the root value of the tree and then work on that. I also wouldn't keep on passing in a list and then append values to it. I think it makes more sense to build up the list value through the stacked return calls.

Based on how you defined your BST I wrote up a brief solution to your problem using one function. I haven't tested it yet since I didn't have your data structure so let me know if there are any bugs.

```
def list_range(node, low, high):
    # base case values for each side of the tree
    lowerHalf = []
    upperHalf = []
    # You have to check each node separately since one could be not None
    # You also have to check that the subtree can even satisfy your value
    if node.left != None and node.root >= low:
        lowerHalf = list_range(node.left, low, high)
    if node.right != None and node.root <= high:
        upperHalf = list_range(node.right, low, high)
    # if the root value is in the range then we just stick it in the middle of both return values
    if low <= node.root <= high:
        return  lowerHalf + node.root + upperHalf
    # otherwise we keep stepping down
    else:
        return lowerHalf + upperHalf
```

Comment: yes this is good. but self is like node for me... because I am using it in a class.

Comment: Then pass in self when you call it. You should use this function as opposed to what you have above because stacking the return calls in this way is more correct than appending the result and the default value thing is a hack.